# Folders and nodes data structure in Meteor

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

I want to make a kind of a file manager, having folders and nodes, where nodes are placed in folders.

Some nodes are placed in "root" while other are placed in folders/subfolders. What is the best approach to this? Should I make `folderId` required for every node or should I assume that the node is placed at root if `folderId = null`?

I want a list of folders at the left and the selected node at the right. But if no node is selected, what can be shown at the right and how should the routes be defined? I guess I don't need a `folderList` since the folder list is always present at the left, so I should only make a route for the selected node; however, if no node is selected, this route will probably cause an error.

Are there any meteor/node.js/javascript examples solving this? From Facebook's messaging system, it seems that if no conversation is selected, it redirects the user to the latest used conversation.

If I want a folder/file structure, I guess two collections (Folders and Files) should be mixed. Should I merge these collections on the client or should I make just one collection (Nodes), having a field `isFolder` and only if the doc is a folder, it can have child nodes?